# PlacesService search results length

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am making calls to the **google.maps.places.PlacesService**'s search() method.
The request object I am sending looks like this:

> var request = {
>               location: map.getCenter(),
>             radius: _radius,
>             types: [document.getElementById("type").value]
>           };

where the location, radius, and, types are properly initialized, e.g., location is the geocoded location of **'New York, NY'**, the radius is **5000m** and types is **dentist**.

The number or results I get is too small (~20) compared to what I get when I go to maps.google.com and do a similar query there. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: show some results and what else you tried to do

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places):

> *"By default, each Place search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results,
>   split across three pages. Additional pages are available via the
>   PlaceSearchPagination object."*

For more information please read the [Accessing Additional Results](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#PlaceSearchPaging) section of the documentation.